# Metal shader language: Why their is difference in result of similar instructions?

Tags: metal

Under metal shader, Why those 2 lines do not work the same :

```
float b = (color.rgb * float3(1,1.1,0.9)).x;
```

and

```
float b = dot(color.rgb, float3(1,1.1,0.9));
```

Comment: What does 'egal instructions' mean in English?

Comment: What you mean by "not work the same"?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 gave completely different result. As I can not debug shader I can not say you exactly, but they are diffirent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are different operations. `*` is *component-wise multiplication*, while `dot` is the vector *dot product*.

Suppose `color` is defined as `float3(0.6f, 0.7f, 0.8f)`.

Then the first expression, `(color.rgb * float3(1.0f, 1.1f, 0.9f)).x`, first multiplies the vectors together component-wise, producing the vector `(0.6, 0.77, 0.72)`, then takes the first component (`x`), so the result is `0.6`.

The second expression, `dot(color.rgb, float3(1.0f, 1.1f, 0.9f))`, is the sum of the component-wise products of the vectors (often called the *dot product* or *inner product*), so the result is `(0.6 * 1.0 + 0.7 * 1.1 + 0.8 * 0.9)`, which happens to be `2.09`.